# Why are my network connections being rejected?

Tags: linux, centos, networking, firewall, libvirt

I have a CentOS 8 guest running on a Fedora 31 host. The guest is attached to a bridge network, `virbr0`, and has address `192.168.122.217`. I can log into the guest via ssh at that address.

If I start a service on the guest listening on port 80, all connections from the host to the guest fail like this:

```
$ curl 192.168.122.217
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 192.168.122.217 port 80: No route to host
```

The service is bound to `0.0.0.0`:

```
guest# ss -tln
State    Recv-Q    Send-Q        Local Address:Port        Peer Address:Port

LISTEN   0         128                 0.0.0.0:22               0.0.0.0:*
LISTEN   0         5                   0.0.0.0:80               0.0.0.0:*
LISTEN   0         128                    [::]:22                  [::]:*
```

Using `tcpdump` (either on `virbr0` on the host, or on `eth0` on the guest), I see that the guest appears to be replying with an ICMP "admin prohibited" message.

```
19:09:25.698175 IP 192.168.122.1.33472 > 192.168.122.217.http: Flags [S], seq 959177236, win 64240, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 3103862500 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
19:09:25.698586 IP 192.168.122.217 > 192.168.122.1: ICMP host 192.168.122.217 unreachable - admin prohibited filter, length 68
```

There are no firewall rules on the `INPUT` chain in the guest:

```
guest# iptables -S INPUT
-P INPUT ACCEPT
```

The routing table in the guest looks perfectly normal:

```
guest# ip route
default via 192.168.122.1 dev eth0 proto dhcp metric 100
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 linkdown
192.168.122.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.122.217 metric 100
```

SELinux is in permissive mode:

```
guest# getenforce
Permissive
```

If I stop `sshd` and start my service on port 22, it all works as expected.

What is causing these connections to fail?

---

In case someone asks for it, the complete output of `iptables-save` on the guest is:

```
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [327:69520]
:FORWARD DROP [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [285:37235]
:DOCKER - [0:0]
:DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 - [0:0]
:DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 - [0:0]
:DOCKER-USER - [0:0]
-A FORWARD -j DOCKER-USER
-A FORWARD -j DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1
-A FORWARD -o docker0 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o docker0 -j DOCKER
-A FORWARD -i docker0 ! -o docker0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i docker0 -o docker0 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 -i docker0 ! -o docker0 -j DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 -j RETURN
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 -o docker0 -j DROP
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 -j RETURN
-A DOCKER-USER -j RETURN
COMMIT
*security
:INPUT ACCEPT [280:55468]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [285:37235]
COMMIT
*raw
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [348:73125]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [285:37235]
COMMIT
*mangle
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [348:73125]
:INPUT ACCEPT [327:69520]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [285:37235]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [285:37235]
COMMIT
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [78:18257]
:INPUT ACCEPT [10:600]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [111:8182]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [111:8182]
:DOCKER - [0:0]
-A PREROUTING -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j DOCKER
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.17.0.0/16 ! -o docker0 -j MASQUERADE
-A OUTPUT ! -d 127.0.0.0/8 -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j DOCKER
-A DOCKER -i docker0 -j RETURN
COMMIT
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Well, I figured it out. And it's a doozy.

CentOS 8 uses [nftables](https://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php/Main_Page), which by itself isn't surprising.  It ships with the `nft` version of the `iptables` commands, which means when you use the `iptables` command it actually maintains a set of compatibility tables in nftables.

However...

Firewalld -- which is installed by default -- has *native* support for nftables, so it doesn't make use of the iptables compatibility layer.

So while `iptables -S INPUT` shows you:

```
# iptables -S INPUT
-P INPUT ACCEPT
```

What you *actually* have is:

```
        chain filter_INPUT {
                type filter hook input priority 10; policy accept;
                ct state established,related accept
                iifname "lo" accept
                jump filter_INPUT_ZONES_SOURCE
                jump filter_INPUT_ZONES
                ct state invalid drop
                reject with icmpx type admin-prohibited  <-- HEY LOOK AT THAT!
        }
```

The solution here (and honestly probably good advice in general) is:

```
systemctl disable --now firewalld
```

With firewalld out of the way, the iptables rules visible with `iptables -S` will behave as expected.

Comment: That seems like more of a workaround or hack then a solution

Comment: Note that depending on the environment I disable things too but this sounds like a WAN facing VM host? In which case I'd think security is important

Comment: It's not a WAN facing VM, and I'm not sure what gave you that impression.  But in any case, you'll note that I didn't suggest disabling your firewall.  Just `firewalld` itself. In fact, I explicitly point out that you can now use the legacy `iptables` command to manage your firewall.

Comment: Thanks so much for coming back here to document your finding... My system seemingly somehow during a kernel switched the fw implementation and showed the same behaviour. I had been looking desperately for a few hours, till I like you ran into the prohibited bit `tcpdump` output. as it's my own switches/routers etc. it was very hard to find why it behaved like a firewall blocking _tutto_ when in there there wasn't one.

Answer (score 1):

In case you do not intent to disable firewalld then solution would be is to add mentioned below nftables rule on the hypervisor host.

1. First add docker0 to internal zone if you haven't use another specific one:

   ```
   firewall-cmd --zone=internal --change-interface=docker0 --permanent
   firewall-cmd --reload
   ```
2. Run nftables to apply rule to accept tcp traffic to 80 port to virbr0 interface with destination 192.168.122.217:

   /sbin/nft add rule inet firewalld filter_FWDI_internal_allow oifname "virbr0" ip daddr 192.168.122.217 tcp dport 80 counter accept comment "comment something"
3. Also need to add iptables rule (or convert it to nftables for consistency see below):

   ```
   /usr/sbin/iptables -t filter -I FORWARD -p tcp -o virbr0 -d 192.168.122.217 --dport 80 -j ACCEPT -m comment --comment "comment something"
   ```

These two rules you may wrap with shell script and add systemd service unit with a delay set to 5 sec. To have it running automatically during boot.

Also it's possible to convert iptables rule to nftables and save both of them to nftables ruleset. But once you'll run converted iptables rule then iptables will be locked out and any new changes to iptables will be possible to do only with firewalld and nftables.

In addition need to have a customized kernel tuntables which make packets traversing the bridge to not go through iptables. [Net.bridge.bridge-nf-call and sysctl.conf](https://wiki.libvirt.org/page/Net.bridge.bridge-nf-call_and_sysctl.conf)

```
sysctl net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables=0
sysctl net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-arptables=0
sysctl net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-ip6tables=0
```

Note, if you'll add it to sysctl.conf it may not automatically apply during reboot as it's a known bug (depending on your Linux distribution).