# Kubuntu 21.10: All ports (open or closed) return ICMP admin-prohibited, even with no firewall enabled. How to fix?

Tags: networking, firewall, icmp

Running an up-to-date installation of Kubuntu 21.10.

If I run any network service on the machine, I'm unable to reach it from anywhere else on my network. The error is always "Host unreachable". A `tcpdump` scan reveals the SYN packet does reach the host, but an ICMP "admin-prohibited" packet is immediately sent back. The packet never even reaches `iptables` (verified by adding a rule that would match a connection, and it's counter never increases)

`nmap` is also unable to detect the port as open, however its scan does show up in the counter. `nmap` interprets the port as filtered because the prohibited packet is ICMP; no response to the SYN packet is sent.

Here is the `tcpdump` output, on the host machine with a service actively listening on port 8000, that appears when another machine tries to connect:

```
04:43:09.154362 IP 192.168.1.3.56608 > 192.168.1.183.8000: Flags [S], seq 3664350430, win 64240, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 2819866111 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
04:43:09.154417 IP 192.168.1.183 > 192.168.1.3: ICMP host 192.168.1.183 unreachable - admin prohibited filter, length 68
```

Here is what happens when `nmap` scans:

```
04:44:49.060156 ARP, Request who-has 192.168.1.183 tell 192.168.1.3, length 46
04:44:49.060177 ARP, Reply 192.168.1.183 is-at 74:e6:e2:da:19:0f, length 28
04:44:49.156156 IP 192.168.1.3.33094 > 192.168.1.183.8000: Flags [S], seq 4114316293, win 1024, options [mss 1460], length 0
04:44:49.156260 IP 192.168.1.183 > 192.168.1.3: ICMP host 192.168.1.183 unreachable - admin prohibited filter, length 52
```

`iptables` is *completely* clear, `ACCEPT` policy on all default chains, no rules whatsoever on `filter`, `nat` and `mangle`.

Services *can* be accessed locally using `localhost` or the machine's IP on the machine itself. The only issue is trying to access from the network.

I do have Docker on the machine, but for trying to figure this out, I disabled Docker and removed all of its `iptables` rules and chains. If services are started as Docker containers, they *are* able to be reached from the network. But I am trying to run a service *outside* of a container.

The machine also has VirtualBox installed, if that's relevant, but at the time of testing no VirtualBox machines were running.

Also of important note is that the SSH server running on the host *can* be reached successfully - this is the only service that is reachable, regardless of what else is running:

```
Starting Nmap 7.91 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2022-01-26 11:00 UTC
Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.183
Host is up (0.00035s latency).
Not shown: 65534 filtered ports
PORT      STATE SERVICE
22/tcp    open  ssh
MAC Address: *redacted*
Too many fingerprints match this host to give specific OS details

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 78.45 seconds
```

Is there perhaps a kernel setting somewhere that is causing this to occur?

Edit: As requested here is `iptables-save` output, but it's totally empty...

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.7 on Wed Jan 26 06:17:24 2022
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
COMMIT
# Completed on Wed Jan 26 06:17:24 2022
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.7 on Wed Jan 26 06:17:24 2022
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
COMMIT
# Completed on Wed Jan 26 06:17:24 2022
```

Comment: Edit your question and post `sudo iptables-save` output please.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov It's literally completely blank, no rules whatsoever, I even cleared the Docker chains just in case. But I posted it anyway.

Comment: That looks weird, I've no idea what could be going on. Any network devices between these servers/PCs?

Comment: Just for sure. Can you post ```sudo ifconfig``` and ```ip a``` output please?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out Kubuntu [has the same "issue" as recent CentOS releases](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/552857/why-are-my-network-connections-being-rejected) in that it uses `nftables`, so `iptables` can be completely clear but there's still another firewall playing with the IP stack.

The quick solution, if you want to disable this extra firewall and just use iptables, is to execute:

```
sudo systemctl disable --now firewalld
```